# Adding button to a view created using uipageviewcontroller

Tags: ios, mobile

[In this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/), is it possible to add a button only to the first view,i.e index == 0?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In the page content view controller, there is a property called pageIndex (NSUInteger).**

The pageview controller sets this property when making a new content page.

So let's say u have 2 content pages, then the first has a pageIndex property of 0 and the next will be 1.
All you have to do is to check if the pageIndex is equal to 0 (meaning it's the first content page) and implement a button to that page.

Assuming you know how to make a button, in the page content view controller put this in stead of your current viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if(self.indexNumber == 0) {
       // code to make your button.
    }
}
```

Comment: @mahi vamsi Either you're trolling, or you're incredibly lazy.

Answer (score 1):

In MainViewController.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {

 //PageView Controller Code
  UIPageViewController  *pageVcObject = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    pageVcObject.dataSource = self;
    pageVcObject.delegate = self;

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-100);
//    [pageVcObject.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [pageVcObject.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [pageVcObject.view setFrame:frame];
    ChildVcForPageViewController *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];
    [pageVcObject setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:pageVcObject
     ];
    [[self view] addSubview:[pageVcObject view]];
    [pageVcObject didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

**#pragma mark - UIPageViewControllerDataSource Methods**

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(ChildVcForPageViewController *)viewController

{


    NSInteger index = [viewController index];
     pageControl.currentPage = index;
    index++;



    if (index == imagesArray.count)
        return nil;
    else
    {

        return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
    }



}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(ChildVcForPageViewController *)viewController

{

    NSInteger index = [viewController index];
    pageControl.currentPage = index;

    if (index == 0) return nil;

    index--;


    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (ChildVcForPageViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)indexValue
        {
            ChildVcForPageViewController *childViewController = [[ChildVcForPageViewController alloc] init];

            childViewController.index = indexValue;

            return childViewController;
        }
```

In ChildVcForPageViewController.h declare the property like below

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger index;
```

then you add the code in ChildVcForPageViewController.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 

{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    if(self.index == 0) {
       // code to make your button.

UIButton *buttonz = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        buttonz.frame = CGRectMake(160, 0, 160, 30);
        [buttonz setTitle:@"Charge" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [buttonz addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        //add the button to the view
        [backImageView addSubview:buttonz];
    }
}
```